# Attachment in SSRS subscription different from report when manually executed

Tags: excel, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a problem that I've never seen before. I have report subscriptions that run early in the morning (between 7 and 8 am) and deliver excel files via email. The reports have run for months without incident.

Recently a few of the excel files delivered via SSRS Email subscription in the morning are blank or contain an incomplete data set. However, if I execute the same report/subscription manually 2 or 3 (between 9 and 10 am) hours later the correct results are in the attachment.

Can someone help me understand and fix this problem?

Comment: Did you check SSRS log? It could be a network issue. Also check if your data have changed during last days causing the dataset query behaves different and arbitrary.

Comment: @Alejandro- Thanks for the suggestions. I don't have permissions for the Report Server (Although I'm working on it). I've asked someone else to check the log.  I don't believe the data itself has changed in the manner you suggest, but I'll look into it.

Comment: Look for things that are happening at that time - backups causing database locks, scheduled jobs impacting server performance and causing timeouts, even poor SQL execution plans that fail when the database server is cold but succeed when it is warmed up and everything is cached. The fact that you can run the report later and it works suggests that there is some environmental factor happening at that time that is impacting data retrieval.

Comment: Do you know if there are automated prcesses running after that that update tables or antything like that? I would try automating it to kick off around 9 or so and see ifthe problem still happens. You could also ask the DBAs and see if they know of anything.

Comment: @wes Thank you for the suggestions. I've asked these questions and currently looking into a few ideals. I came across an article that I think explains the problem. It suggests SSRS notification and event processes related to subscription delivery via email are running out of sync (I'm paraphrasing the best I can here). I have between 25 to 40 subscriptions delivered by email at the same time every weekday. I'm going to stagger the delivery times of a few and see it that resolves the issue. Again everyone thanks for the replies.

Comment: @ChrisLätta Thank you for the reply I appreciate your comments.